# Get-ADUser returns nothing

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm currently working on a script which extracts some names stored in a .csv file and should display some information about the AD account of that user.

The names may be stored like this `han solo` or `solo han`, but always divided by a space. Those names can contain at least umlauts and who the hell knows what else.

Every user has an attribute called `name`, which looks like this `solo, han` (essentially "surname, given name").

This is the line I'm currently using:

```
Get-Content -Encoding:string C:\Temp\admin.mh\Reports\User_AD.csv |
select -skip 1 | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "User" -Delimiter "," | %{
   $arr = $_.User.Split(" "); 
   Get-ADUser -Filter {(Name -eq "$($arr[1]), $($arr[0])") -or (Name -eq "$($arr[0]), $($arr[1])")} 
}
```

The first bit is somewhere from Google, which stated that this is the way to get the incoming encoding right.

If I manually type in the name (even with umlauts) I get the right result, but when I store it in the array I never get any results, even with no special characters at all.

I was able to reproduce this exact behaviour on the commandline by creating the array like this `$arr = @("han", "solo")` and using the exact same filter. If I leave the variables out and filter manually like `name -eq "solo, han"` everything works fine.

Comment: Swap curly braces for double quotes in `-Filter` and use single quotes in place of double quotes.

Comment: Dude, that worked! Thanks a lot! If you could provide it as an answer and maybe an explanation of the difference I'm gonna give you an accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ADUser` does not support script block filtering, instead you should use a string-based filtering. But, you can use `-eq` and other comparison operators in the filter. Also `Get-ADUser` requires string values to be surrounded by single quotes. So your filter should be like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(Name -eq '$($arr[1]), $($arr[0])') -or (Name -eq '$($arr[0]), $($arr[1])')"
```